# Microsoft Teams App - Add Authentication and Authorization for Task/Fetch Card Action

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

Located in the BotBuilder-Samples GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples

There is a sample app: **54.teams-task-module**. This app demonstrates a task/fetch action with a Url to a Custom Form which is rendered by a Razor Page.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module

In the Bot, the `OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync` method is overridden to return a `TaskModuleResponse` which tells the system to fetch the URL passed back to Teams in the response.

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/54.teams-task-module/Bots/TeamsTaskModuleBot.cs

```
 protected override Task<TaskModuleResponse> OnTeamsTaskModuleFetchAsync(ITurnContext<IInvokeActivity> turnContext, TaskModuleRequest taskModuleRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var asJobject = JObject.FromObject(taskModuleRequest.Data);
        var value = asJobject.ToObject<CardTaskFetchValue<string>>()?.Data;

        var taskInfo = new TaskModuleTaskInfo();
        switch (value)
        {
            case TaskModuleIds.YouTube:
                taskInfo.Url = taskInfo.FallbackUrl = _baseUrl + "/" + TaskModuleIds.YouTube;
                SetTaskInfo(taskInfo, TaskModuleUIConstants.YouTube);
                break;
            case TaskModuleIds.CustomForm:
                taskInfo.Url = taskInfo.FallbackUrl = _baseUrl + "/" + TaskModuleIds.CustomForm;
                SetTaskInfo(taskInfo, TaskModuleUIConstants.CustomForm);
                break;
            case TaskModuleIds.AdaptiveCard:
                taskInfo.Card = CreateAdaptiveCardAttachment();
                SetTaskInfo(taskInfo, TaskModuleUIConstants.AdaptiveCard);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return Task.FromResult(taskInfo.ToTaskModuleResponse());
    }
```

I have enabled developer tools in Teams and watched the network requests, as well as overridden every method I can find to try find an extensibility point to inject some sort of token into the request so that the URL can be secured from public anonymous access.

**Question**: The only way to provide authorization on the Razor Page I see right now is passing the token on the query string and using a custom authorization handler to process the token.

Is there a better way to inject a token or any other info into the task/fetch request so that the request can be authenticated and authorized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comments: Looking at it as "Web inside Adaptive" and revisiting the sample project and your information it does seem the "CustomForm" razor page is initializing the Teams JavaScript SDK.

**This DOES mean I can authenticate this content using the SSO as you mentioned.**

I had only thought it would work in a TAB, not inside a bot card.Solved, follow the tabs javascript SDK guidance.

Answer (score 0):

To be clear on this, authentication -is- possible, but only for web pages (Adaptive Cards don't need it). This auth would rely on the standard SSO Teams offers for Task Modules as well as Tabs. See here for intro guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-aad-sso?tabs=dotnet, especially:

> The SSO API also works in task modules that embed web content.

So really your question kind of becomes "how do I do SSO for web content in Teams". Here's a great video, which includes a link to text (blog) version of the content: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/lets-decode-single-sign-on-sso-in-microsoft-teams-tabs/. Here's a working sample, with both Node and DotNet backend options: https://adoption.microsoft.com/sample-solution-gallery/pnp-sp-dev-teams-sample-tab-sso. Note that the samples and docs generally focus on doing an OnBehalfOf (OBO) operation to call Graph, but the principle remains the same - you get a JWT token that you can pass back to your backend, which you can then validate. You can also, from the token, get user info for the logged in user.

Comment: Thank you. I am familiar with the OAUTH cards and flow and can obtain tokens for my users through authentication. I reviewed this but it doesn't seem to directly apply to the specific case I am referring to. I am familiar with the SSO. In this case, the bot is returning a TaskModuleResponse back to Teams, and the final fetch for the card content seems to come directly from the Teams desktop client to the URL. The use cases on the web only show fetching public resources such as New User Registration or a product detail page. My only thought as of now is to append the token to the URL.

Comment: Appending the token to the URL is a VERY bad idea - the TRAFFIC over HTTPS is encrypted, but I don't think the URL is, so a 'man in the middle' could grab your token straight off the url. In simple terms, you'd be destroying the value of httpS itself that way!

Comment: In any case, I'm still struggling to understand your concern. The traffic between the user and the bot is already secured, via Teams. The web page itself is publicly available, but is there something sensitive on the page *itself*? If so, don't render it client side, rather do it via a backend API request from within the page (i.e. javascript), because THAT call you can secure with a JWT token - Teams SSO will give you the token, and you can send it as a Bearer token in the Auth header - that's what the samples show. That token can be fully validated server side in the API.

Comment: Sorry, I absolutely agree token on url=bad, but am thinking along the lines of a public client in an oauth scenario receiving a short-lived access token to a resource. I was investigating the option to provide a token and render user specific content from the task/fetch action in teams. It may very well be that this is not an intended use case, and I would fall back to server-side rendering as you also suggest. I am simply learning a new platform and experimenting with options

Comment: More succinctly: is there a proper way to use a task/fetch action to obtain user specific authenticated content from an external resource by injecting a bearer token into the request Teams makes directly to the url specified in the task/fetch action. Once the task/fetch action is passed back to teams, it seems there is no further ability to modify the outgoing request. This leads me to believe task/fetch should only be used for public unauthenticated resources

Comment: Again, there are two scenarios - adaptive card and web. For adaptive card, you can completely control via the bot what gets rendered, and you can present authenticated content using bot SSO. For web, you're correct that the -initial- load of web resources needs to be unauthenticated, but then it's your own code, you can do inside there whatever you want. If you want to show authenticated content, implement the SSO and make a secure call with the token you receive to the backend - that basically IS the model. Teams has specific support for the SSO built it to make it more seamless to the user.

Comment: You are missing the third scenario which I am asking questions about here: Adaptive Cards which return a task/fetch action and a URL. This would be a combination of both Adaptive and Web by your definitions. I am rendering an adaptive card server-side with authentication information which return as task/fetch module and url back to teams. Control is transitioned to Teams and teams makes the request, With a TAB I can use SSO. With a bot I have access to the token. With an Adaptive card task/fetch I seem to have nothing. I am simply trying to confirm this fact to understand the valid use cases.

Comment: See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/task-modules/task-modules-bots?tabs=nodejs  which states: "A new kind of invoke message task/fetch: Using the invoke card action for Bot Framework cards, or the Action.Submit card action for Adaptive cards, with task/fetch, task module either a URL or an Adaptive Card, is fetched dynamically from your bot."

Comment: Looking at it as "Web inside Adaptive" and revisiting the sample project and your information it does seem the "CustomForm" razor page is initializing the Teams JavaScript SDK. This should mean I could authenticate this content using the SSO as you mentioned. I had only thought it would work in a TAB, not inside a bot card. I will experiment and update. Thank you. Aside: I do see that there would be no reason to do this when it can be done on the back-end. This is mostly an exercise for me to gain a complete understanding of the platform capabilities.

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much what I was trying to say - I think you're heading in the right direction now. Give it a go and let me know how it goes.